# How do I fix poor performance in Matlab with an AMD R5 M330 GPU?

Tags: drivers, graphics, 20.04, amd-graphics, matlab

I've just upgraded to ubuntu 20.04 from 19.10.

The "problem" is while checking that the programs that I use daily are working, I find that Matlab gives me this error

```
javax.media.opengl.GLException: X11GLXDrawableFactory - Could not initialize shared resources for :0....
```

For fix it I have to double click on the icon -> open with dedicated GPU.

But now when I create a graph or a surf with Matlab, they become "poor quality and laggy ". In other words, they aren't as they were in the 19.10

I have the suspicion that my GPU isn't used at all. I have the impression that only the intel Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] is working

Some info

**lspci | grep -E 'VGA|Display|3D'**

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)

01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / Radeon 520 Mobile] (rev 83)
```

**lshw -c display | grep driver**

```
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0

configuration: driver=radeon latency=0

LC_ALL=C lspci -v | grep -EA10 "3D|VGA" | grep 'prefetchable'

Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]

Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
```

**Why not in list the 2gb?**

Let me know if there are other info that i could give.

*[ plus question: when i watch video on youtube or shared screen on skype or similar i find a  the high cpu usage ( 40 - 50 % ) and the fans start spinning hard ]*

**UPDATE**

SEE [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247556/20-04-fixing-recursive-fault-but-reboot-is-needed)
**sudo lshw -C display**

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:129 memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / Radeon 520 Mobile]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:130 memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:a1300000-a133ffff ioport:5000(size=256) memory:a1340000-a135ff
```

Comment: You didn't include the resources line from the lshw output, but probably both Memory lines are for the Intel graphics.  Check your BIOS settings for possible suppression of the discrete graphics.  Check your /etc/modprobe.d files for blacklisting of the Radeon driver. Does lsmod show the radeon driver?

Comment: Please install `vainfo` package and add the output of `vainfo` command to the question.

Comment: which version of matlab are you using?

Comment: @SimonB matlab 2019b

Comment: @ubfan1 I've run this command  lshw -C display. Is this that you want? also note the link that i've update, maybe it's related

Comment: @N0rbert i update the question with a link, maybe it's related

Comment: Your original lspci output only had memory associated with the Intel driver. (maybe got cut off in posting?)  Are your Radeon drivers from the standard repositories?  Looks like the new kernel had trouble making the new Radeon driver.  Try a reconfigure or a purge/install of the Radeon drivers.

Comment: @ubfan1 no this is all i got with that command. Yes i also think that the kernel had some trouble. have you seen the link with another error? i think it's created by the radeon driver. Could you point me the direction to purge/install the driver ? thank you man for your time!

Comment: I never had Radeon hardware, but generally try the standard repos first: ensure the Software and Updates/Ubuntu Software/Restricted(multiverse) is checked, run sudo apt-get update, and try ubuntu-drivers to see what's offered.  If you really need a later version than offered, try adding the graphics-drivers ppa, update, etc.

Comment: thank you  @ubfan1