# 20.04 - fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, 20.04

it's just a week that I upgrade to ubuntu 20.04 ( I was in 19.10 before).

I think I have a problem with the graphic card ( [see this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247543/problem-with-amd-r5-m330-gpu-a-2-gb-dedicated-gpu-ubuntu-20-04))

Today I found a new error when I restart the system. It seems that it occurs in the old version of Ubuntu, I have no found related question with the new version.

What could i do to solve this problem?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many posts out there with similar questions.
I recall once having a problem (possibly the same) and solving with a change in GRUB:

Edit the default boot line (`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`) in `/etc/default/grub`, adding `acpi=off nomodeset xforcevesa`.
Then

```
$ sudo update-grub
$ sudo shutdown -r
```

Possibly related:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412075/fixing-recursive-fault-but-reboot-is-needed-on-x3850-x6-sles12
(emulex card driver upgrade is posted as the solution)

[Error "fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50451/error-fixing-recursive-fault-but-reboot-is-needed)

Comment: thank you for the answer, but after some month i decide to reinstall the os. Maybe your answer could help someone